# How do I find info about a class in a complex C++ code?

Tags: c++, oop, visual-studio-code

I am trying to understand a complex set of .cpp / .h files which are assembled into a Physics code.
Inside one .cpp file, there is an overloaded function call operator() which reads:

```
void IonizationTunnel::operator()(..., Patch *patch, ...) {
    ...
    ...
    double ran_p;
    ran_p = patch -> rand_ -> uniform();
}
```

I want to check what uniform() does (i.e. spits numbers between 0 and 1 or between other values).

I went onto Patch.cpp and found this:

```
rand_ = new Random(params.random_seed);
```

Patch.h file has:

```
Random * rand_;
```

**What is the method to identify information about this Random class or any other class which I cannot find its implementation between hundreds of .cpp/.h files and tens of thousands of lines of code?**

I am using VisualStudioCode with the WLS1 addition (i.e. to browse / edit files in my WSL1 app downloaded from MicrosoftStore).

Thank you!

Comment: *There is no Random.cpp or Random.h file.* -- Whatever tool you're using should tell you where this is located.  You having to assume where it is defeats the whole purpose of using such a tool.

Comment: Dear Paul, I have edited the q. I have found via a terminal search a file called Random.h. I have found the method uniform() defined and implemented in there. The q's remains relevant: is there any other way to search for such a class rather than manually searching for a Random.h/Random.cpp? Thank you!

Comment: Your edit doesn't change the fact that these type of search tools should take you directly to where the function, variable, whatever, is defined.  You shouldn't need to do the search yourself.  For example, Intellisense in Visual Studio takes you directly to the definition / declaration if it is part of your project.

Comment: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/editingevolved#_go-to-definition

Comment: jtbandes, thanks for that. I believe my VisualStudioCode is broken or I do not know how to use it. I cannot do any of the commands explained in the link and I have never seen such a rectangle appearing on any of my vars/types. Thank you!

Comment: Typical solution is to use real IDE ;) Visual Studio (**not** VS Code) has IntelliSense, that allows you to navigate between functions, by either F12 with caret on function name or by left click with Ctrl.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using Atom, you can try to click on "Find", then "Find in project", and then try the expression "Random" or "class Random" or "struct Random".

Other IDEs should have similar functionalities (see comments to the question).